# Stream Writable end called before write callback

Tags: node.js, stream, node.js-stream

Using Readable Stream, Transform stream and a Writable stream, I have a strange behavior, my Writer.end() get called before the _write callback.

Here I copy/pasted a sample of a faulty code :

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
function Reader() {
  Readable.call(this, { objectMode: true });
  this.data = [{id: 1}];
}
util.inherits(Reader, Readable);
Reader.prototype._read = function () {
  console.log('_read');
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.push(this.data.pop() || null);
  }.bind(this), 1000);
};

var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
function StringifyStream(options) {
  Transform.call(this, options);
  this._writableState.objectMode = true;
  this._readableState.objectMode = false;
}
util.inherits(StringifyStream, Transform);

StringifyStream.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
  setTimeout(function()  {
    this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk));
    cb();
  }.bind(this), 100);
};

var Writable = require('stream').Writable;
function Writer() {
  this.string = '';
  Writable.call(this);
}
util.inherits(Writer, Writable);

Writer.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  console.log('_write', arguments);
  this.string += chunk;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('write done')
    callback();
  }, 1000);
};

Writer.prototype.end = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  console.log('end', arguments);
  if(callback) callback();
};

var reader = new Reader();
var change = new Change();
var stringify = new StringifyStream();
var writer = new Writer();

reader.pipe(change).pipe(stringify).pipe(writer);
```

And the output:

```
_read
_read
_write { '0': <Buffer 7b 22 69 64 22 3a 31 2c 22 70 72 6f 75 74 22 3a 31 7d>,
  '1': 'buffer',
  '2': [Function] }
end {}
write done
```

Comment: What you've shown is expected. It writes data and then calls `.end()` on the stream to close it because there is no more data to write. Then since you put a timer inside `_write()`, it fires 1 second later, way after `.end()` was called.

Comment: But the _write callback is called in the timeout. So I didn't tell the previous stream in pipe that I was done writing the current chunk.

Comment: That doesn't matter. `end` just signifies that no more data will be written, it doesn't need to wait for the previous chunk to be processed in order for upstream to tell the writable stream that no more data is coming in. It's merely setting a flag in the writable stream's state.

Comment: Ok, it's just the reader telling there won't be anymore data to come. I thought it was to tell that all data had been flushed. Thanks !